Fabric: Shortcut tables not showing in SQL endpoint
I have a fabric capacity with two workspaces. I have some tables in a Warehouse in one of them, let's call it ws1, I have shortcut those in my Lakehouse in the workspace ws2.
In ws2 I can in the SQL endpoint see all the shortcut tables. I have a notebook that reads from the shortcut tables and talks to an API. It stores the Id value from the table and the Id value I get from the API and stores those in a new table.
In ws2 I can see this new table with the Ids in the SQL endpoint for that Lakehouse. I have then made a shortcut for this table to a Lakehouse in ws1, but it doesn't show up in the SQL endpoint for ws1.
There are only three text columns in the table. I don't do anything special to the table when I save it with my notebook.
Is there somewhere I can see why it doesn't show up? Like an error or something.
I have already tried deleting the shortcut and creating it again. I thought that might fix the issue, but it didn't.
I also checked the SQL endpoint for ws2 and the table shows up no problem. So, I don't see there could be anything corrupt with the table, since then it wouldn't show up there either.

I actually figured it out. The issue was permissions. The owner of ws1 didn't have any permissions on anything in ws2. We tried with Viewer to no avail, but Contributor on the Lakehouse was the thing that made it work.
So, to sum up the shortcut will have the same permissions as the user who owns the item that the shortcut is made from. I hope this will help others who runs into this problem.
